# Split a list inside a list

Tags: python, string, list

Say that I have this list

```
List=[[‘this’ ],[‘is’],[‘a’],[‘sentence’]]
```

And I want  to split the inside lists so the output look like this

```
List=[[‘t’,’h’,’i’,’s’],[‘i’,’s’],[‘a’],[‘s’,’e’,’n’,’t’,’e’,’n’,’c’,’e’]]
```

I tried

```
print([j  for i in list for j in i ])
```

but the output came as  `[‘this’,’is’,’a’,’sentence ‘]`

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 adjustments you need:

1. You have sublists of length 1. Therefore, you need to access index 0 of each sublist.
2. Your desired result has sublists within your results list. So you need inner list comprehensions *within* your outer list comprehension.

Here's an example:

```
lst = [['this'],['is'],['a'],['sentence']]

res = [[i for i in sublist[0]] for sublist in lst]

print(res)

[['t', 'h', 'i', 's'],
 ['i', 's'],
 ['a'],
 ['s', 'e', 'n', 't', 'e', 'n', 'c', 'e']]
```

The inner sublist comprehensions can be written more succinctly by feeding strings directly to `list`:

```
res = [list(sublist[0]) for sublist in lst]
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling `list` on a string will return a list of the characters that make it up. This can be done, e.g., in a list comprehension:

```
lst = [['this'], ['is'], ['a'], ['sentence']]
result = [list(x[0]) for x in lst]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call `list()` on a string to get a list of composing characters as:

```
>> list("anmol")
>> ['a', 'n', 'm', 'o', 'l']
```

Similarly, you need to convert each of your string to a list as:

```
>> l = [['this' ],['is'],['a'],['sentence']]
>> [list(i[0]) for i in l]
>> [['t', 'h', 'i', 's'], ['i', 's'], ['a'], ['s', 'e', 'n', 't', 'e', 'n', 'c', 'e']]
```